# Getting ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded whenever trying yo import Shared Module IONIC

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

am getting *ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded* whenever i import my shared module in my component

Here is my Shared Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { LocationPickerComponent } from './location-picker/location-picker.component';
import { ImagePickerComponent } from './image-picker/image-picker.component';

@NgModule({
imports: [
        FormsModule,
        CommonModule,
        IonicModule,
    ],

    declarations: [LocationPickerComponent, ImagePickerComponent],

    exports: [LocationPickerComponent, ImagePickerComponent]

})
export class SharedModule { }
```

here i wanna use this two component i.e `LocationPickerComponent, ImagePickerComponent` in my **new-offer** component

**new-offer.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { NewOfferPageRoutingModule } from './new-offer-routing.module';
import { NewOfferPage } from './new-offer.page';
import { SharedModule } from 'src/app/shared.module';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    SharedModule

  ],
  declarations: [NewOfferPage]
})
export class NewOfferPageModule {}
```

this new-offer componenet is basically child of offers componenet
**offers.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { OffersPageRoutingModule } from './offers-routing.module';
import { OffersPage } from './offers.page';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: OffersPage
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    OffersPageRoutingModule,
   RouterModule.forChild(routes)

  ],
  declarations: [OffersPage],
})
export class OffersPageModule {}
```

here is **app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, MapModalComponent],
  entryComponents: [MapModalComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig), AngularFireDatabaseModule, HttpClientModule, AgmCoreModule.forRoot({ apiKey: 'AIzaSyA8noLb6pKChcnmsi1jr1FsQNBbHSZiUK0' }), GooglePlaceModule, AngularFireStorageModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    { provide: BUCKET, useValue: '' }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Not sure, but I think 3 modules is 1 too many. My current project has over 30 components in app.module alone. A prime place to look is in any module that imports the same components as others. You can find root cause by reducing imports and exports untill the error goes away.

Comment: Error goes away when I remove one component from **Shared Module** but how can i use the removed component